# Is there a CSS technique to style inline elements so that they scroll faster (and appear closer) than neighboring elements?

Tags: html, css, parallax

I intend to **style words** on a web page so that they **appear to float** between the page and the user. For example, I'm using text shadows as a visual cue that the shadowed words are at an elevation relative to the surrounding words.

I'm interested in **using parallax as another visual cue**: ideally, elevated words would scroll faster than the rest of the page. However, I want these words to **remain inline**, rather than shove them in another div (which is a technique that others have demonstrated for successfully achieving a parallax effect).

*Is there a way to do this— to create an inline element that scrolls faster than its parent and sibling elements, using CSS and not resorting to scripts?*

Comment: How do you imagine an inline element which is scrolling faster than a parent? It should at least break all the layout

Comment: I do not believe this is possible using CSS alone. I was going to suggest using JavaScript to manage paddings/margins to achieve the effect but then read that you do not want a scripted solution. I would research calc and Moz effects, it may lead you down the right path if there is one...

Comment: Could you at least show an example even using not desirable option so we could see it and suggest a solution

Comment: Here is a good example of a non-inline parallax solution:

https://keithclark.co.uk/articles/pure-css-parallax-websites/demo3/

Notice that the text that scroll at different speeds are children of different parents.

Comment: An option that I imagine is possible, but do not know how to implement myself, would be to set the transform of elements to translateZ(something), and to have them all share a perspective origin that stays in the center of the browser window while the page scrolls.

Comment: And here is a Codepen that shows a proof of concept for scrolling elements using a static perspective origin: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/erbRma?editors=1100